# Django migrate sqlite3 db to postgres Query invalid input syntax for integer: "none" error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

My project use Django 2.0 database from sqlite migrate to postgresql 9.6.3, Run normal in sqilet, migrate to postgresql and running error.

models.py :

```
Class WechatPay(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField('网点', max_length=20, default='None')
    user_group = models.CharField('渠道', max_length=20, default='None')
    total_fee = models.FloatField('订单金额', default=0, decimal_places=0, max_digits=7)
    card_sale = models.FloatField('售卡款', default=0, decimal_places=0, max_digits=7)
    card_recharge = models.FloatField('充值款', default=0, decimal_places=0, max_digits=7)
    trade_date = models.DateField('交易日期', auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py :

```
def group_list(request):
    start_time = request.GET.get('start_time', datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    end_time = request.GET.get('end_time', datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    object_list = WechatPay.objects.values('user', 'trade_date', 'user_group').filter(
    trade_date__gte=start_time).filter(
    trade_date__lte=end_time).filter(
    status='SUCCESS').annotate(
    card_sale=Cast(Sum('card_sale'), DecimalField(decimal_places=2)),
    total_fee=Cast(Sum('total_fee'), DecimalField(decimal_places=2)),
    card_recharge=Cast(Sum('card_recharge'), DecimalField(decimal_places=2))
).order_by('-trade_date')
summary = WechatPay.objects.filter(
    trade_date__gte=start_time).filter(
    trade_date__lte=end_time).filter(
    status='SUCCESS').aggregate(card_sale_sum=Cast(Sum('card_sale'), DecimalField(decimal_places=2)),
                                total_fee_sum=Cast(Sum('total_fee'), DecimalField(decimal_places=2)),
                                card_recharge_sum=Cast(Sum('card_recharge'), DecimalField(decimal_places=2)))
return render(request, 'wechatpay/data-group.html',
              {'items': object_list, 'start_time': start_time, 'end_time': end_time,
               'summary': summary})
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\workspace\venv\venv-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "none"
LINE 1: ...LECT SUM("gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."card_sale")::numeric(No...
                                                             ^
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\workspace\venv\venv-django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "D:\workspace\venv\venv-django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "D:\workspace\venv\venv-django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\workspace\venv\venv-django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\workspace\weixin_pay\gft_web\gft_wechat_pay\views.py", line 249, in group_list
card_recharge_sum=Cast(Sum('card_recharge'), DecimalField(decimal_places=2)))
File "D:\workspace\venv\venv-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 374, in aggregate
return query.get_aggregation(self.db, kwargs)
File "D:\workspace\venv\venv-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 476, in get_aggregation
result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
File "D:\workspace\venv\venv-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1063, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "D:\workspace\venv\venv-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
File "D:\workspace\venv\venv-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "D:\workspace\venv\venv-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "D:\workspace\venv\venv-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "D:\workspace\venv\venv-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "D:\workspace\venv\venv-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "none"
LINE 1: ...LECT SUM("gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."card_sale")::numeric(No...
```

queries sql:

```
SELECT "gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."user", "gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."trade_date", "gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."user_group", SUM("gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."card_sale")::numeric(None, 2) AS "card_sale", SUM("gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."total_fee")::numeric(None, 2) AS "total_fee", SUM("gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."card_recharge")::numeric(None, 2) AS "card_recharge" FROM "gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay" WHERE ("gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."trade_date" >= 2018-01-27 AND "gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."trade_date" <= 2018-01-27 AND "gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."status" = SUCCESS) GROUP BY "gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."user", "gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."trade_date", "gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."user_group" ORDER BY "gft_wechat_pay_wechatpay"."trade_date" DESC
```

I try change models.py field type, from FloatField to DecimalField,but views save to zero.
models.py:

```
Class WechatPay(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField('网点', max_length=20, default='None')
    user_group = models.CharField('渠道', max_length=20, default='None')
    total_fee = models.DecimalField('订单金额', default=0, decimal_places=0, max_digits=7)
    card_sale = models.DecimalField('售卡款', default=0, decimal_places=0, max_digits=7)
    card_recharge = models.DecimalField('充值款', default=0, decimal_places=0, max_digits=7)
    trade_date = models.DateField('交易日期', auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py:

```
def qrcode(request, cost):
    """ Insert data """
    trade_log = WechatPay()
    total_fee = int(result[0].get('total_fee')) / 100
    print(f'receive data {total_fee},date type {type(total_fee)}')
    trade_log.total_fee = Decimal(total_fee)
    print(trade_log.total_fee)
    print(type(trade_log.total_fee))
    trade_log.save()
```

Console:

```
receive data 0.21,date type <class 'float'>
0.2099999999999999922284388276239042170345783233642578125
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

But database save "total_fee" field is 0.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One potential issue here could be how you're trying to store NULL values with the database.  In Django/Python, you pass in the NULL values using `None`.  This needs to be converted to `NULL` when you execute your actual SQL statement, which Django should handle under-the-covers.  That may be the reason for your initial syntax error above.

If you get past the syntax error, try changing this line:

```
total_fee = int(result[0].get('total_fee')) / 100
```

Instead of `100` try using `100.00` and see if that retains your decimal precision when you update the DB.

If that doesn't work, then look at this line:

```
total_fee = models.DecimalField('订单金额', default=0, decimal_places=0, max_digits=7)
```

Try changing `"default=0"` to `"default=999"`.  If you run your code and see the value set to 999, then that means no value was passed in and that gives a place to start looking.

Comment: i try changing "default=0" to "default=999". but save value is 0.

Comment: What about the `total_fee = int ...` line?  Try changing the division to `100.00`.  If that doesn't work, hard-code this value `total_fee = 999` to make sure it's actually updating.

Comment: if passed in value < 100, then save 0; if passed in value > 100 then save value // 100 .

Comment: Is change views.py total_fee = int(result[0].get('total_fee')) / 100.00

Comment: db postgresql total_fee Data type is numeric

Comment: Are you trying to store as an INTEGER or a DECIMAL?  In this line, 

`total_fee = models.DecimalField('订单金额', default=0, decimal_places=0, max_digits=7)`, you have `decimal_places=0`.  If you want to store as a DECIMAL, try changing it to `decimal_places=2` for example.

Comment: thanks，it is decimal_places=2 , I ignore it... poor english... thanks you again